# how to make open the translation dialog in chrome via html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, translation, google-translate

The question is : is it possible to replace in a more elegant way the old "deprecated" https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website/

"We no longer provide new access to Google Translate's Website Translator. This change does not affect existing use of the Website Translator.
We encourage users looking to translate webpages to use browsers that support translation natively."

••• This code brings a "select" old style (not very goog for mobile phones)

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> function googleTranslateElementInit() {  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "en",multilanguagePage: true,layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,autoDisplay: false}, "google_translate_element");}</script>
```

the question is HOW to create a html button (or clickable img) to "ask" google to open the translation dialog in a certain language ??

I want to have few flags representing different languages and when a user click spanish flag, it trigger chrome to ask the user if he wants to translate the page in spanish ?
is there a javascript or html5 way to do so ?

Regards

Comment: I still get confused, do you wanted to create a translation page using google translate API ?

Comment: Hi @FahmiJabbar it's an old question. I managed to used the newest google API and make my own language menu

Comment: How did you do it, @Jintor?

Comment: @luislhl see my summary answer (it's more pin pointed and more targeted) the older version (the one in the question) made some time the whole site go crazy because of div, span css not always translated... see a live example here with google API : https://www.stubfeed.com/feed/12389437059965

Comment: @FahmiJabbar see my summary answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is long so I make a short summary

0. you need a google API key and able translation (there is a google step by step tutorial here : https://neliosoftware.com/blog/how-to-generate-an-api-key-for-google-translate/ )
1. Make an array with list of desired languages see https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages for more details
2. make a select with options out of this list
3. on each options attach a onclick that triggers an ajax function and return the translated text to the desired div

php function could look like this

```
$cgoog = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?target='.strtolower($langCode).'&key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY_PHP.'&q='.urlencode($text);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cgoog);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$execurl = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($execurl, true);

return $response['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'] ?? '';
```

note that the double ?? is the php 7 null coalescing operator (in short it's a if !isset or else in 1 operator...) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce